# asp.net mvc table does not update after filtering with checkboxes

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am doing the ticket application and I am making filtration of items with checkboxes. First the page loads every item in database and view displays it in the table. Then a user can click on the checkbox and view displays just the selected categories. It is supposed to be updated on the checkbox click.

Controller Action:

```
 public ActionResult Display(int[] checkId)
        {
            if (checkId == null)
            {
                DispDisplayVM viewModel = new DispDisplayVM
                {
                    Jidlos = db.Jidlos.ToList(),
                    //Jidlos = (from Jidlo jidlo in db.Jidlos where checkId.Contains(jidlo.CategoryID) select jidlo).ToList(),
                    Categories = db.Categories.ToList()

                };

                return View(viewModel);
            }
            else
            {
                DispDisplayVM viewModel = new DispDisplayVM
                {
                    //Jidlos = db.Jidlos.ToList(),
                    Jidlos = (from Jidlo jidlo in db.Jidlos where checkId.Contains(jidlo.CategoryID) select jidlo).ToList(),
                    Categories = db.Categories.ToList()

                };

                return View(viewModel);
            }
}
```

Data into controller are passed by ajax. It can be one value or an array. Then there is a LINQ query to filter database.

View:

```
@using jidloApp.Classes
@using jidloApp.Models
@model DispDisplayVM


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Display";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Display</h2>

<div class="container">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Disp")" class="btn btn-default pull">Pridat novy recept</a>
</div>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkId">
        Kuřecí
    </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="2" name="checkId">
        Vepřové
    </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="3" name="checkId">
        Hovězí
    </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="4" name="checkId">
        Krůtí
    </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="5" name="checkId">
        Vegetariánské
    </label>
</div>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nazev Jidla</th>
                <th>Kategorie</th>
                <th>Akce</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             @foreach (Jidlo jidlo in Model.Jidlos)
             {
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => jidlo.name)
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => jidlo.Category.popis)
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = jidlo.JidloID }) |
                         @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = jidlo.JidloID }) |
                         @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = jidlo.JidloID })
                    </td>
                 </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
</table>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[name="checkId"]').click(function () {
            getSelectedCheckBoxes();
        });

        var getSelectedCheckBoxes = function () {
            var idArray = [];
            $('input[name="checkId"]:checked').each(function () {
                idArray.push($(this).attr("value"));
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Display", "Disp")',
                type: "POST",
                data: { checkId: idArray },
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function () {
                    alert("ajax request to server succeed");
                }
            });

    };
    });


</script>
```

Data filtering is working fine and requested data are passed into the view correctly.

What is not working is when I click on the checkbox, the table stays the same as before and does not update. I really can not find what is wrong here. Can you please give some advice what to do?

Btw the table updates when I create new item in database or I delete it...

Comment: Because you do not do anything with the view your return (and in should be `return PartialView(viewModel);`). You need to update the DOM in the seccess callback - e.g. `success: function (response) {$(someElement).html(respomse); }`

Comment: It works now as it should. Thanks. First partial view and script which loads the partial view at the beginning and then on click function when filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a View and a PartialView.
Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}

public PartialViewResult Display(int[] checkId)
{
   DispDisplayVM viewModel = null;
   [youre code]

   return PartialView(viewModel)
}
```

Index View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Display";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Display</h2>

<div class="container">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Disp")" class="btn btn-default pull">Pridat novy recept</a>
</div>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkId">
        Kuřecí
    </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="2" name="checkId">
        Vepřové
    </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="3" name="checkId">
        Hovězí
    </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="4" name="checkId">
        Krůtí
    </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="5" name="checkId">
        Vegetariánské
    </label>
</div>

<div id="data-container"></div>

<script>
    $('input[name="checkId"]').on("click",function () {
        var idArray = [];
        $("input[name="checkId"]:checked").each(function () {
            idArray.push($(this).attr("value"));
        });

        $("#data-container").load("@Url.Action("Display", "Disp")",{ checkId: idArray });
    });
</script>
```

Display View:

```
@using jidloApp.Classes
@using jidloApp.Models
@model DispDisplayVM

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nazev Jidla</th>
            <th>Kategorie</th>
            <th>Akce</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            @foreach (Jidlo jidlo in Model.Jidlos)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => jidlo.name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => jidlo.Category.popis)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = jidlo.JidloID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = jidlo.JidloID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = jidlo.JidloID })
                </td>
                </tr>
            }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Code written "on fly"

Comment: I had to add this at the start of the script:  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#data-container").load("@Url.Action("PartialDisplay", "Disp")");
    });  ...but I got the basics from you. Thank you.

Comment: Why? Just put @Html.Action("PartialDisplay", "Disp") inside data-container.